# Blender 2.8 does not render current camera view

Tags: modeling, rendering, camera

Why doesn't blender 2.8 render the view from the currently selected camera; this view:

[image]

produces:

[image]

How can I render an image viewed from a specific camera?

Comment: You have more than one camera, make sure that the one you want is the active one for the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the comments of this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FO-7K6k1XaY

"If you just want to switch between cameras: Select Camera, Press CTRL+NUM0. Last selected will be new main camera."

Answer (score 0):

select the camera press 'n' and in view check 'use local camera'